# How to select distinct records based on a given condition?

Tags: sql

I have the following table in the MySQL database:

```markdown
| id | col | val |
| -- | --- | --- |
| 1  | 1   | y   |
| 2  | 1   | y   |
| 3  | 1   | y   |
| 4  | 1   | n   |
| 5  | 2   | n   |
| 6  | 3   | n   |
| 7  | 3   | n   |
| 8  | 4   | y   |
| 9  | 5   | y   |
| 10 | 5   | y   |
```

Now I want to distinctly select the records where all the `value`s of similar `col` are equal to `y`. I tried both the following queries:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `col` FROM `tbl` WHERE `val` = 'y'
```

```sql
SELECT `col` FROM `tbl` GROUP BY `col` HAVING (`val` = 'y')
```

But it's not working out as per my expectation. I want the result to look like this:

```markdown
| col |
| --- |
| 4   |
| 5   |
```

But `1` is also being included in the results with my queries. Can anybody help me building the correct query? As far as I understand, I may need to create a derived table, but can't quite figure out the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, with the second query.  Instead, compare the min and max values:

```
SELECT `col`
FROM `tbl`
GROUP BY `col`
HAVING MIN(val) = MAX(val) AND MIN(`val`) = 'y';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that 'y' is the minimum value:

```
HAVING MIN(val) = 'y'
```